# Array Multiplication

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

new programmer here and I am a little confused on this code sample I'm working on. Basically I'm taking arrayA and passing it down to my method, I would then like my method to take and multiply each adjacent numbers, therefore my total should come out to 962, return it back to main and sopln it out.

```
 public class 8a
    {
       public static void main(String [] args)
       {
          int [] arrayA = {10,5,100,3,6,2,30,20};
          int result = sumOfProducts(arrayA);        
       }

       public static int sumOfProducts(int [] a)
       {
           int counter = 1;

           for(int x = 0; x < a.length; x++)
       }

    }
```

Comment: Your for-loop has no body, so it does nothing.  You need to add the code that does the math you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure 962 is the correct result? If you multiply each adjacent number and sum up the results, your return value should be 1540. You seem to take only every other pair into consideration:

```
10*5 ok
5*100 not
100*3 ok
3*5 not 
...etc.
```

If you want to sum up of the results of every adjacent pair multiplication (also the ones marked with 'not'), you can simply go through the array like this:

```
       int sum= 0;
       for(int x = 0; x < arrayA.length-1; x++)
         sum+=(arrayA[x]*arrayA[x+1]);
```

On the other hand, if you are REALLY 100% sure you want to leave out every other pair and get to the 962 result:

```
       int sum= 0;
       for(int x = 0; x < arrayA.length-1; x+=2)
         sum+=(arrayA[x]*arrayA[x+1]);
```

However, this only works for arrays with an even number of entries. And since this is part of an exercise, i would consider the first solution to be far more likely to be the indended one.